# Javascript Count Down in div

Tags: javascript, countdown

i have fallowing code on first load all ok, when i get new time with post countdown values -2 instate of -1

here is my code:

```
<span id="countdown_side_bar"></span>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {

                            App.counter_side_bar(1000, 500);
                        });
                    </script>

counter_side_bar: function (end, start) {

        this.container = $('#counter_side_bar');
        this.endDate = new Date(end * 1000);
        this.startDate = new Date(start * 1000);
        if(new Date().getTime() > this.endDate){
            this.container.html('Countdown Ended');
        }
        else{

            var context = this,
                updater = function () {
                    context.startDate.setSeconds(context.startDate.getSeconds() + 1);
                    var timediff = (context.endDate - context.startDate) / 1000;
                    if (timediff < 0) {
                        context.container.html('Battle Now');
                    }
                    else {
                        context.container.html(App.formatedTime(timediff));
                        setTimeout(updater, 1000);
                    }
                };

            updater();
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `new Date().getTime() > this.endDate //<--these values look like completely different formats to me. are you sure that works?`

Comment: other than that, this is not intelligible:  > when i get new time with post countdown values -2 instate of -1

Comment: yes code works on first load,

Comment: Agree with @sweaver2112 the above line look like in different format. `new Date().getTime()` will return unix stamp and your `this.endDate` is standard javascript time strings.

Comment: that's what i am calculating between start and end time (unix stamp) on days,hours,minutes,seconds format

Comment: @AliGüzel do you mean values are decreasing by steps of 2 (like10,8,6...2,0) instead of steps of 1 (10,9,8...2,1,0) ?